# How to control version of source code before deploying with svn

Tags: svn, version-control

I have example for my question

Ex.

1. write on file A. (sprint A)
2. build and deploy to UAT/PROD.
3. write on file A. (sprint B)
4. bug on sprint A, I need to fix on file A. (Urgent)

I use SVN. How do I resolve this problem on my project without rolling back source code of each file. Sometimes this occurs with more files.

Should I do it on above example? (I don't want to rollback (sprint B) code, fix and deploy to UAT/PROD)

Comment: Are you using [branching](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html) at all? That seems to be the solution here.

Comment: Read about branching patterns: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html